# Batch script remove everything after a dynamic text from the string/filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, windows-7-x64, batch-rename

I have a string containing filename like below batch script lines:

```
set "file1=name.php_2017_23_08_12_22_07"
set "file2=name.vbs_2016_16_12_12_13_03"
....
```

Now as you see above, the list of filenames and their extensions is variety and I need to get the real filenames with their actual extensions (`.php`, `.vbs`) respectively. So when I pass in a function with filename with extension I should get actual filenames like below:

`call :restoreFile %file2% ".vbs"`

should give me output, removing everything after `.vbs` in the variable `%file2%`:

```
name.vbs
```

And so on for other variables too.

How can set a function like that, which strips a **dynamic substring** from **filename string** ?

I tried the below code, but that doesn't work with dynamic substring or text, which can be substitued from variable:

```
set targetfile=%file2:.vbs=&rem.%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specify the extension - it's still in the name.

Use a `for /f` to split at the first underscore.

```
:restoreFile
Set "FileName="
For /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%N in ("%~1") Do Set "FileName=%%N"
If defined FileName Echo Ren %1 %FileName%
Goto :Eof
```

You may even put the date_time in front of the extension and so avoid possible dupes:

```
:restoreFile
Set "FileName="
For /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%N in ("%~1") Do Set "FileName=%%~nN_%%M%%~xN"
If defined FileName Echo Ren %1 %FileName%
Goto :Eof
```

The ren commands are prepended with an echo, if the output looks OK remove the echo.